# Forcing serving stale content with Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache

I already have a Nginx server configured as caching reverse proxy. I need to configure it so that:

- it **serves stale content** disregarding any HTTP headers it received from the origin server (`cache-control: max-age`, `expires` and the like), thus not requesting fresh content from the origin server even when the cached content has expired
- it **fetches and serves** fresh content only when the cached content is completely missing in the configured cache directory

I've already configured Nginx so that it serves stale content in case of origin server error with [`proxy_cache_use_stale`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale), but I need to serve stale content when the origin server is working too.

I'd assume [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) is the key, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to say "first try the stale cached files, then the origin server".

Is it possibile?

Comment: Why don't you just mirror the site and serve the mirror, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I need to serve the site at the same URL where it is now, and I need `/wp-admin` to be served from the origin server (e.g. not stale)

Comment: Well, then, if you place the cache within the document root then you can certainly serve them with `try_files`. Several WordPress caching plugins work this way. But this still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nginx cache directory has its own structure that's different from the directory layout of the files at the origin server, so internal links would not work anymore